# not able to source a shell / bash file within the .env file

Tags: bash, shell, dotenv, bitrise

I tried so many key words:

1. use `source`
2. `nothing in front of the path`
3. use

```
# set -a # automatically export all variables
'./../private/some-cred.sh'
# set +a
```

None of them allow me to import some private creds into the .env file that will be ran by fastlane  `Dotenv.overload './config/.env.qa'`

Current files:

`./config/.env.qa`

```
# source './../private/fastlane-cred.sh'
# APPLE_API_KEY_ID=$APPLE_API_KEY_ID_PRIVATE
```

`./private/some-cred.sh`

```
export APPLE_API_KEY_ID_PRIVATE="AAA"
```

When this setup got loaded into bitrise (which is in `./ios/`) via  `Dotenv.overload './config/.env.qa'`

The value will be considered as empty.

Any idea what else I should do, in order to allow me to load some variables from a file into .env properly so its recognized?

NOTE: path is correct. because I had a file ref defined within .env file and it was loaded in the bitrise ENV var correctly. but not for variables.

Comment: `./whatever` doesn't source anything; it needs to be `. whatever`.

Comment: In this case that means `. '../private/some-cred.sh'` -- the command is `.`, the filename to be sourced is an argument to that command.

Comment: (Note that the above comments are speaking to shell in general, not to fastlane or Ruby at all; see the answer by Guss for that)

Comment: A `.env` file is not a shell script; even the assignments are not processed as shell assignments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is important to know about the "dotenv" paradigm is that the various "dotenv" implementations are **mimicking** a shell environment instead of actually being a shell environment. As they are run from inside the application, written in a non-shell language - it is far too late at this point to use the shell to setup environment variables. The "dotenv" libraries aren't even actually changing the process's environment - they just use the runtime's API to store data in such a way that other code that uses the runtime's environment access API will see it *as if* it's coming from the environment.

The fastlane system uses the [`dotenv` gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which uses an internal parser (based on regular expressions) to parse a file that looks like a shell file (containing only variable assignment) but isn't an actual shell file. Everything there that doesn't look like a naive shell variable assignment is ignored - the dotenv file isn't actually a shell script and isn't treated like a shell script, so you can't put shell scripting commands in it and expect it to work.

If you really want to use shell scripting to setup your environment - then use a wrapper shell script to start your environment (or a Makefile) instead of using the application's internal "dotenv" support - which as I explained above, isn't actually a shell script.